# Combinatorics - Election of a Commission

Tags: combinatorics

> The following people voted for the election of a commission (subset of the people available for election): a female professor, a male professor, a female employee, a male employee, a female student and a male student. How many ways are there to form a size two commission?

I have $\binom{2+2+2}{2}$ as an answer, since we're looking for combinations of size $2$ from all $6$ people (without replacement). However, my book gives $\sum_{i,j,k\in \{0,1,2\}, i+j+k=2}\binom{2}{i}\cdot \binom{2}{j} \cdot \binom{2}{k}$ as an answer. Why is this correct and what is the reasoning behind this solution?

Comment: Both approaches give $15.$ I would also use yours, which is easier and straightforward. The solution in the book combines all possible choices relatively to the cathegory (professor, employee, student). It is possible that the author of the solution had some didactic focus.